# How to keep observations within duplicates over a maximum value condition?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the head of my dataset.

```
   SM_id                                SM_nom  ...  MRS_CO_VER  Territoire
0    101               Montréal : Centre-ville  ...    V2017-08     3598479
1    102  Montréal : Centre-ville périphérique  ...    V2017-08    14048443
2    103                  Montréal : Sud-Ouest  ...    V2017-08    15130563
3    103                  Montréal : Sud-Ouest  ...    V2017-08         197
4    104        Montréal : Notre-Dame-de-Grâce  ...    V2017-08    10828311
```

There are some duplicates in `SM_id` variable. I would like to keep only the observation that has the maximum value on `Territoire` variable within each unique `SM_id`.

I have tried this :

`MRC_to_SM = MRC_to_SM[MRC_to_SM.Territoire == MRC_to_SM.Territoire.max(level='SM_id')]`

And I get this error:

`level name SM_id is not the name of the index`

How should I proceed?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO, this question is an exact duplicated of the question marked above. Do try out the approaches listed out

Answer (score 1):

You were using the wrong functions. `idxmax` is what you were looking for:

```
idx = df.groupby('SM_id')['Territoire'].idxmax()
df = df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

Comment: It works. Thanks